# Swapping columns of a matrix without numpy

Tags: python

I need to swap the columns of a given matrix by applying some function to `(M,i,j)` to swap the `i`<sup>th</sup> and `j`<sup>th</sup> columns of `M`.

```
def swap_columns(M,i,j)
    rows = M[i]
    col = M[i][j]
    for i in M:
        N = M[i][j]
        M[i][j] = M[j][i]
        M[j][i] = N
    return N
```

Unable to get this working at all.

Comment: Do you want to create a new matrix with the columns swapped or modify the matrix in-place without creating a new object? Can you include examples of your matrices so we know their layout?

Comment: @Oli: Both of those things are fairly obvious from the question IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this function:

```
import copy

def my_swap(M, i, j):
    temp = copy.deepcopy(M)
    for k in range(len(M)):
        temp[k][i] = M[k][j]
        temp[k][j] = M[k][i]
    return temp
```

Answer (score 3):

In `python` variable swapping can be done by: `x, y = y, x`

Code:

This function will modify the original matrix. No need to return

```
def col_swapper(matrix, col_1, col_2):
    for line in range(len(matrix)):
        matrix[line][col_1], matrix[line][col_2] = matrix[line][col_2], matrix[line][col_1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it (in-place) using a for-loop to perform the swapping through unpacking of the matrix's rows:

```
def swapCols(M,c1,c2):
    for row,row[c2],row[c1] in ((row,row[c1],row[c2]) for row in M):pass
```

Comment: That's interesting. Does this technique have a name?

Comment: I don't know of a name for it.  "Magic for loop unpacking" perhaps :)